# How can I hyperlink from PowerPoint to Excel, linking to a specific tab and named range or cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

How can I hyperlink from PowerPoint to Excel, linking to a specific tab and named range or cell and make it stick?

I am successful in creating the Hyperlinking and obtaining the desired results, however after I save the PowerPoint file, it deletes the tab and named range that were included in the Hyperlink.

As an example:

> `C:\<file name.xlsx>#<tab name>!<named range or cell>`

.  This works great as entered and links properly until I save the PowerPoint file.

After a save, it truncates the hyperlink after file name.  It opens the Excel file to the last saved location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i did it:

- Copy your cell/range in excel
- Go to powerpoint and click on Paste > Paste special
- Select paste link on the left
- Select attach hyperlink

Save the file and you are good to go.

Comment: Go ahead and click accept then ;)
Glad that I could help.

Comment: Office for Mac v15 doesn't support this.