# Link a Microsoft Excel cell to a specific page of a Microsoft Powerpoint file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink, links

When I click on the contents of a cell on Microsoft Excel, I want a **specific page** of a Microsoft PowerPoint file to be opened. I wonder how I can do that.

I studied a [question](https://superuser.com/q/552724/556382) on linking PowerPoint to Excel, but my case is the other way around, i.e. Excel to PowerPoint.

I tried doing the following method, but rather than 3rd page (`#3`), it just shows the 1st page:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried filename.ext#PageNumber format in hyperlink e.g. to link to 3rd slide of test.ppt link should be <path>\test.ppt#3

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. Updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: "...didn't help", "...didn't work" - *How* didn't it help, *how* didn't it work? Does it throw an error? Does it just sit there, does it go to the wrong slide, etc.?

Comment: The link you provided, "this" refers to a link to an Excel Sheet linking between Excel Sheets.

Comment: @BruceWayne Applied your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.

- your Presentation is saved as *.pptx
- your Power Point Show, is *.ppsx, something you are pointing to.

Your PPT: **Save-As**: name.**ppsx**

EX) How to point to **slide number 3** in a **PPT slide show**, from Excel:

- **name.ppsx#3**

Answer (score 0):

Late, but this worked for me, so whoever finds this question and is stuck like I was, maybe you find this helpful.

Building on the suggestion by patkim, I tried the following (which seems to work so far): Using the full path for the *.ppt file in question, I prefixed the full path with `file:///` and appended the slide number like so: `#1234`.

It also requires the file to be open in PowerPoint.